# How to enable assert in CQ5/ OSGi Bundle (Java)?

Tags: java, osgi, aem, assert, osgi-bundle

We enable asserts in a core java application by doing `java -ea xxx`, I also know how to enable assertions in eclipse by changing the commandline options.

But how to enable assert in an OSGi bundle. I have a bundle that I want to test with assertions enabled and I want to disable them at the time of deployment(Disabling would be easy as assert is disabled by default). But how to enable it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the `ClassLoader#setDefaultAssertionStatus(Boolean)` method. It sets the assertion status only for classes that hasn't been loaded yet. Therefore, the best place to put this statement would be a bundle activator:

```
public class Activator implements BundleActivator {

    @Override
    public void start(BundleContext bundleContext) throws Exception {
        getClass().getClassLoader().setDefaultAssertionStatus(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void stop(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
    }
}
```

Remember to register the activator in the `maven-bundle-plugin` configuration:

```
<project>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <instructions>
            <Bundle-Activator>my.project.Activator</Bundle-Activator>
...
```

Comment: Well I use CRXDE Eclipse so I don't need to register activator. My Activator will always be active. I'll try this and let you know.